# NSURL with Pipes |

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, cocoa-touch

I'm trying to initialize an `UIImage` via URL.
This is the code I wrote:

```
NSString * path = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[[_tours objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]objectForKey:@"map_url"]];
    NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:path];
    NSData *data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:url];
    UIImage *img = [[UIImage alloc]initWithData:data];
    [[cell tourPreviewImage]setImage:img];
    ....
```

An example `map_url` looks like the following:

```
https://maps.google.com/maps/api/staticmap?size=200x200&maptype=roadmap&markers=size:big|color:green|72.3601030185,41.4626763775&markers=size:big|color:red|45.4563468516,94.4774796973&sensor=false
```

It seems that the `NSURL` Object cant handle the | Pipe Character the right way because i dont get any image data. If I delete the parameters separated by the pipe out of the url everything works fine.

Any Ideas how to solve this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ok i found a solution for this. Encoding is what did go wrong.

```
NSString * path = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[[_tours objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]objectForKey:@"map_url"]];
path = [path stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:path];
NSData *data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:url];
UIImage *img = [[UIImage alloc]initWithData:data];
[[cell tourPreviewImage]setImage:img];
```